# References and Arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, reference

I'm new to programming in general and references in particular. I want to manipulate individual objects in an array by reference, so that I'm not working on mere copies of the objects I wanted to stick into the array. My question is how to do that.

For example, suppose I have these lines of code:

```
$obj0 = blah;
$obj1 = blah;
$obj2 = blah;
$myArray = array($obj0, $obj1, $obj2);
```

When I now access and modify `$myArray[1]`, will this be the same as modifying `$obj1`? Or would I have to be modifying `&$myArray[1]` instead?

Comment: Are you using PHP5 and are those $objN actual objects, or variables?

Comment: Yes, I'm using PHP5, and I intended them to be variables with objects as values. Sorry if I'm confused/confusing in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it stands, no you will not alter the initial variables.

If you wish to do it by reference, you should put those ampersands when you setup the array like so.

```
$myArray = array(&$obj0, &$obj1, &$obj2);
```

Code:

```
    $a = "cat"; $a1 = "cat";
    $b = "dog"; $b1 = "dog";
    $arrRef = array(&$a, &$b); $arrCopy = array($a, $b);
    $arrRef[0] .= "food"; $arrCopy[0] .= "food";
    $arrRef[1] .= "house"; $arrCopy[1] .= "house";
    echo "a: $a   b: $b <br />";
    echo "a1: $a1   b1: $b1 <br />";
```

Output:

```
a: catfood b: doghouse
a1: cat b1: dog
```

Comment: check this out: http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php     you might not want to make that by-reference array after all.  here is an alternative

Answer (score 1):

No, modifying `$myArray[1]` is not the same as modifying `$obj1`.  However, if you are operating on the object that they both point to, that object will be changed.

In other words:

```
// Does not affect $obj1, but it does affect $obj1->foo
$myArray[1]->foo = "bar";

// Does not affect $obj1, which continues to point to the same object
$myArray[1] = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP5 objects are called "by reference" by default so there is no need to prepend `$myArray[1]` with '&'.

Comment: -1 The statement "PHP5 objects are called by reference" must die. I know it is in the official PHP documentation but it is just plain wrong! PHP objects are actually bound to variables by references, yes. But those references are copied by '=' or when using it as an argument, like any other variable. If you trully want a "by reference" semantic, the only (only) way is to use the & operator. See @thisMayhem answer